# cakephp log an array as var_dump

Tags: php, cakephp, logging, var-dump

I need to jump into a server side code. It is used cakephp there. I would like to see a variable, I think it is a model, but I am not sure, let be a variable in or case.

```
CakeLog::write('debug', 'myArray'.var_export($myArray) );
```

it will have the output

```
myArray: Array
```

I would like to see similar output as var_dump can produce to the output.

Is that possible? if yes, than how?

Any help apreciated.

Comment: I simply did var_dum($myarray); in my controller and I got the resulted array printed in my view. may it help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just use [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php), it accepts a second argument not to output the result.

```
CakeLog::write('debug', 'myArray'.print_r($myArray, true) );
```

And if you don't want new lines, tabs or double spaces in your log files:

```
$log = print_r($myArray, true);
$log = str_replace(array("\n","\t"), " ", $log);
$log = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',$log);
CakeLog::write('debug', 'myArray' . $log);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
CakeLog::write('debug', 'myArray'.print_r($myArray, true));
```

The `true` parameter makes print_r return the value rather than print on screen, so you can save it.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Answer (score 0):

Somebody got a redirection method presented [here](http://www.nolte-schamm.za.net/2011/05/php-var_dump-into-error-log/).

This I have used to see what I have there, and it shows very clear.

Comment: This guy uses `ob_start()` to get the return value of a `var_dump()`, which is what `print_r($var, true)` does internally. Seems he is using an old version of php.